# Check if a map is empty in xslt

Tags: xslt

I create a map variable and want to check if it has items.

```
<xsl:variable as="map(xs:string, xs:string)*" name="ancestorsMap">
        <xsl:map>
            <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
                <xsl:variable name="ancestor" select="(ancestor::node()[not(descendant-or-self::layer)])[1]/@xml:id"/>

                <xsl:if test="exists($ancestor)">
                    <xsl:map-entry key="string(@xml:id)" select="string($ancestor)"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:map>
    </xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="check">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="empty($ancestorsMap)">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'NaN'"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$ancestorsMap"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
```

When it is empty, the oXygen variable panel shows:
**Value type:** map(*)[1](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_empty.html)
**Value:**     map{}

I tried [fn:empty()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_empty.html) so far

Comment: Why is the variable typed as `as="map(xs:string, xs:string)*"`? That means you don't expect a single map of type `map(xs:string, xs:string)` but rather any sequence, including an empty one. Then inside you create a single `xsl:map`. So perhaps you want a different type `as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"` and then the check in your answer is one possible way.

Comment: Note that a map is an item, and every item is a sequence of length 1, so empty() applied to an item will always return false.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Indeen I don't want to have any `item()` but rather a `map()`. But if I type the variable `as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"` and there are no string values to put in, I'll get a _type error_, didn't I? Maybe to type it as `as="map(xs:string*, xs:string*)"` would be the proper solution?

Comment: No,  `<xsl:variable as="map(xs:string, xs:string)" ...` should work fine for an empty map with no entries. See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamL6 for a quick test. I don't think `map(xs:string*, xs:string*)` is a possible map type, for the key type you can't use a sequence, only an atomic type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
test="map:size($ancestorsMap) = 0"
```

works fine. But maybe there are better approaches.

Comment: That's certainly the most direct and obvious approach. There are others, such as `empty(map:keys())`, but they don't have much to recommend them. It's just possible, of course, that counting the number of entries in a map is an expensive operation, whereas getting the first key is cheap; it all depends on the implementation.